# Infinite Caching generator

Tags: python, generator, primes

I am working on a project that requires a lot of small primes a lot of times. I want to create a generator that can run forever, but caches the values produced already. Here is my code so far.

```
from itertools import count

def prime_sieve(): # postponed sieve, by Will Ness
    for c in (2,3,5,7):                     # original code David Eppstein,
        yield c
    sieve = {}                              # Alex Martelli, ActiveState Recipe 2002
    ps = prime_sieve()                      # a separate base Primes Supply:
    p = next(ps) and next(ps)               # (3) a Prime to add to dict
    q = p*p                                 # (9) its sQuare
    for c in count(9,2):                    # the Candidate
        if c in sieve:                      # c’s a multiple of some base prime
            s = sieve.pop(c)                # i.e. a composite ; or
        elif c < q:
            yield c                         # a prime
            continue
        else:   # (c==q):            # or the next base prime’s square:
            s=count(q+2*p,2*p)       #    (9+6, by 6 : 15,21,27,33,...)
            p=next(ps)               #    (5)
            q=p*p                    #    (25)
        for m in s:                  # the next multiple
            if m not in sieve:       # no duplicates
                break
        sieve[m] = s                 # original test entry: ideone.com/WFv4f

class cached_primes:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prime_gen = prime_sieve()
        self.done = False
        self.vals = []
        for value in self._gen_new(0, 3):
            pass

    def get(self, start=0, end=float('inf')):
        vals = self.vals
        if start == 0:
            lo = 0
        else:
            lo = bisect_left(vals, start)

        if vals[-1] > end:
            hi = bisect_right(vals, end, lo=lo)
            yield from islice(vals, lo, hi)
            return
        yield from islice(vals, lo, len(vals))
        yield from self._gen_new(start, end)

    def _gen_new(self, start, end):
        for prime in self.prime_gen:
            print(prime)
            self.vals.append(prime)
            if start <= prime <= end:
                yield prime
            elif end < prime:
                return
```

The problem with this code is that if multiple sources are generating new primes, they will skip the ones that the other generates. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you really need to re-implement a prime-sieve and a cache???

Comment: If the primes are small, then the list of small primes will also be small.  Just generate them once in a list and reuse that list?

Comment: I am trying to write code to make an infinite generator of Mersenne primes, so while the primes will all be relatively small (at least compared to other numbers throughout the program), I eventually need arbitrarily large primes.

Comment: This code is incredibly clever. So clever, in fact, I'm not really sure what it does or how it works.

Comment: Share the cache as a class variable instead of an instance variable, but always access it with a lock.

Comment: You're going to be a lot better off using an ordinary prime generator and just saving new values off to a list when needed. This implementation is needlessly complex and very hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I figured out to do it. It isn't that clean though.

```
class cached_primes:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prime_gen = prime_sieve()
        self.done = False
        self.vals = [2]
        next(self.prime_gen)

    def get(self, start=2, end=float('inf')):
        vals = self.vals

        lo = bisect(vals, start)
        if vals[-1] >= end:
            hi = bisect(vals, end)
            yield from islice(vals, lo, hi)
            return
        else:
            while vals[-1] < end:
                if len(vals) > lo:
                    bound = len(vals)
                    yield from takewhile(lambda p: p <=end, islice(vals, lo, bound))
                    lo = bound
                vals.append(next(self.prime_gen))
        hi = bisect(vals, end)
        yield from islice(vals, lo, hi)
```

Answer (score -1):

Python generators only yield each value once. Once the value has yielded, it will never be yielded again.

This is your problem:

```
def _gen_new(self, start, end):
    for prime in self.prime_gen:
        print(prime)
        self.vals.append(prime)
        if start <= prime <= end:
            yield prime
        elif end < prime:
            return
```

This will grab the primes from `start` to `end` *from where the generator is currently*, not from the beginning. You're trying to use the results from `prime_sieve` multiple times, but as I mentioned before, old primes will get exhausted. This is why it would skip over already generated primes.

You might find `next` to be a helpful function in place of the for loop. You might also consider using functions from `itertools`.

Comment: I am only using one instance of `cached_primes`, that I pass around. What I want to do is figure out when someone has updated the list, and use those values if they have.

Comment: You have a bug in `_gen_new` as well- this is probably the source of a lot of your unexpected behavior. I'm not sure what you're really asking.

Comment: What's the bug?

Comment: You're reusing a generator that may have been exhausted beyond the primes you're looking for. I don't think you really understand what the yield statement does, so you should probably do your research and figure that out before you write any more broken code.

Comment: if you look at the answer I posted, you will see that I have this